# TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len() ,in my python code

Tags: python, typeerror

This is my python code:

```
if len(contours) >= 2:
            old_center[0] = center[0]
            if is_mouse_down:
                Thread(target=gui.mouseUp, args=()).start()
                is_mouse_down = False
```

Comment: `contours` is `None`, and you need to figure out why.

Comment: What is `contours` and where does it come from?

Answer (score 0):

Here, `countours` is `None`, as `None` is not iterable so it doesn't have `len` too. You can modify your logic like :

```
if contours and len(contours) >= 2:
    old_center[0] = center[0]
    if is_mouse_down:
        Thread(target=gui.mouseUp, args=()).start()
        is_mouse_down = False
```

Thanks @mkrieger1 for reporting the issue : you should not use this as a solution. It's just bypassing the problem. You need to figure out why it's `None` in other codes and resolve the issue.

Comment: This will not solve the problem, only hide the symptoms.

Comment: Thank you for reporting the issue. I've updated my answer.